# Function pointer obtained from GetProcAddress crashes the program if it uses the stdlib

Tags: c++, std, loadlibrary

I'm trying to dynamically load a `dll` and call a function from it at runtime. I have succeeded in getting a working pointer with `GetProcAddress`, but the program crashes if the function from the `dll` uses the `stdlib`. Here's the code from the executable that loads the `dll`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

typedef int (*myFunc_t)(int);

int main(void) {
  using namespace std;
  HINSTANCE dll = LoadLibrary("demo.dll");
  if (!dll) {
    cerr << "Could not load dll 'demo.dll'" << endl;
    return 1;
  }
  myFunc_t myFunc = (myFunc_t) GetProcAddress(dll, "myFunc");
  if (!myFunc) {
    FreeLibrary(dll);
    cerr << "Could not find function 'myFunc'" << endl;
    return 1;
  }
  cout << "Successfully loaded myFunc!" << endl;
  cout << myFunc(3) << endl;
  cout << myFunc(7) << endl;
  cout << myFunc(42) << endl;
  cout << "Successfully called myFunc!" << endl;
  FreeLibrary(dll);
  return 0;
}
```

Here's code for the `dll` that actually works:

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" {

  __declspec(dllexport) int myFunc(int demo) {
    //std::cout << "myFunc(" << demo << ")" << std::endl;
    return demo * demo;
  }

}

int main(void) {
  return 0;
}
```

(Note that the `main` method in the `dll` code is just to appease the compiler)

If I uncomment the line with `std::cout` however, then the program crashes after the `cout << "Sucessfully loaded myFunc!" << endl;` line but before anything else gets printed. I know there must be some way to do what I want; what do I need to change for it to work?

Comment: Requiring a main() function to keep the *linker* happy is certainly very, very bad.  That indicates that you are actually building an EXE and not a DLL, possibly by hacking the file extension.  Initialization of the CRT is different in a DLL.  Be sure to use the correct project template to get started.

Comment: _"Note that the main method in the dll.."_ Unless overridden in the linker commands the DLL entry point should be `DllMain`.  That you require a `main` suggests they you have something wrong with the build of the DLL.

Comment: After looking a little harder at the compiler's documentation than I had previously, I realised that @HansPassant and @RichardCritten were right and that I was in fact compiling the latter code as an `exe`, though actually using the `dll` file extension. I fixed that, and the imported function worked fine, even with the line uncommented. Thanks!

Comment: Kudos for adding that main() detail, nobody could have guessed what you might have done wrong without it.  This is a keeper, please complete the Q+A yourself with what you learned.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments, it turns out that the compiler's demands for a `main` function were hints that I was inadvertently making a an `exe` that decptively used the file extension `dll`, not an actual `dll` (because I didn't quite understand the compiler options I was using), which in some way messed up the dynamic loading of that assembly.